# Making a List of FindRoot approximations

Tags: equation-solving, approximation

I have the following function.

```
 c[n_, k_, z_] := Sum[(-1)^j*(z^(n*j + k)/(n*j + k)!), {j, 0, Infinity}]
```

I'd like to find roots of the equation

```
 c[3,1,z]==0
```

And so I set up a table to determine approximate values using the FindRoot function;

```
 Table[FindRoot[c[3, 1, z] == 0, {z, i}], {i, 0, 25}] // TableForm
```

And when I do this, I get a list of 26 values that z is approaching.  These are not exact, and the results are truncated decimals that approximate the solutions near the real values of the first 26 nonnegative integers.  How can I get Mathematica to

1)  Expand the length of the decimal approximations.  I've tried to use the N[exp,#] in the above tables expression but this did not work.  I'll also note that Mathematica can not find the exact roots of this equation.

2)  Enter the decimal approximation of these roots with no repeated values into a list without having to type them all out by hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

c[n_, k_, z_] := Sum[(-1)^j*(z^(n*j + k)/(n*j + k)!), {j, 0, Infinity}]

f[z_] = c[3, 1, z]

(* 1/3 E^-z (-1 + 2 E^(3 z/2) Sin[1/6 (π + 3 Sqrt[3] z)]) *)
```

For a bounded range, [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) will provide exact results expressed as [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects

```
(sol1 = Solve[{f[z] == 0, -1 < z < 26}, z]);
```

The approximate results are

```
sol1 // N

(* {{z -> 0.}, {z -> 3.01674}, {z -> 6.65062}, {z -> 10.2782}, {z -> 
   13.9058}, {z -> 17.5334}, {z -> 21.161}, {z -> 24.7886}} *)
```

A typical root looks like

```
sol1[[2]] // InputForm

(* {z -> Root[{-1/2 + E^((3*#1)/2)*
       Sin[(Pi + 3*Sqrt[3]*#1)/6] & , 3.01674421208407851\
792853936992618024693`20.30243982725732}]} *)
```

The last argument of the `Root` is the approximate numerical value of the root along with the precision of the approximate value

Verifying the results,

```
f[z] /. sol1 // FullSimplify

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Alternatively, use [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) with a bounded range of interest. Use arbitrary-precision by setting the [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) option

```
(sol2 = NSolve[{f[z] == 0, -1 < z < 26}, z, WorkingPrecision -> 20])

(* {{z -> 0}, {z -> 3.0167442120840785179}, {z -> 6.6506245189075155822}, {z -> 
   10.278196280969976183}, {z -> 13.905795126299895029}, {z -> 
   17.533393854261920871}, {z -> 21.160992582732551059}, {z -> 
   24.788591311200977250}} *)
```

Verifying the quality of the results,

```
f[z] /. sol2

(* {0, 0.*10^-20, 0.*10^-18, 0.*10^-17, 0.*10^-17, 0.*10^-16, 0.*10^-15, 
 0.*10^-14} *)
```

Use a [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) to get good initial values for [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
Plot[f[z], {z, -2, 26}, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}]
```

[image]

Use arbitrary-precision by setting the `WorkingPrecision` option

```
sol3 = FindRoot[f[z] == 0, {z, #},
    WorkingPrecision -> 20] & /@
  {0, 3, 7, 10, 14, 18, 21, 25}
```

[image]

```
(* {{z -> 3.7007434154171882626*10^-17}, {z -> 3.0167442120840785179}, {z -> 
   6.6506245189075155822}, {z -> 10.278196280969976183}, {z -> 
   13.905795126299895029}, {z -> 17.533393854261920871}, {z -> 
   21.160992582732551059}, {z -> 24.788591311200977250}} *)
```

Verifying the quality of the results,

```
f[z] /. sol3

(* {3.7007434154171882626*10^-17, 0.*10^-20, 0.*10^-18, 0.*10^-17, 0.*10^-17, 
 0.*10^-16, 0.*10^-15, 0.*10^-14} *)
```